# How do I use gcloud to find which regions my dataproc clusters are in?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

If I issue `gcloud dataproc clusters list` 0 clusters are listed:

```
$ gcloud dataproc clusters list
Listed 0 items.
```

However if I specify the region `gcloud dataproc clusters list --region europe-west1` I get back a list of clusters:

```
$ gcloud dataproc clusters list --region europe-west1
NAME                WORKER_COUNT  STATUS   ZONE
mydataproccluster1  2             RUNNING  europe-west1-d
mydataproccluster2  2             RUNNING  europe-west1-d
```

I'm guessing that the inability to get a list of clusters without specifying `--region` is a consequence of a decision made by my org's administrators however I'm hoping there is a way around it. I can visit https://console.cloud.google.com/ and see a list of all the clusters in the project, can I get the same using `gcloud`? Having to visit https://console.cloud.google.com/ just so I can issue `gcloud dataproc clusters list --region europe-west1` seems a bit of a limitation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying regional services are by-design isolated from each other such that there's no single URL that returns the combined list (because that would be a global dependency and failure mode), and unfortunately, at the moment the layout of the gcloud libraries is such that there's no option for specifying a list of regions or shorthand for "all regions" when listing dataproc clusters or jobs.

However, you can work around this by obtaining the list of possible regional stacks from the Compute API:

```
gcloud compute regions list --format="value(name)" | \
    xargs -n 1 gcloud dataproc clusters list --region
```

The only dataproc region that doesn't match up to one of the Compute regions is the special "global" Dataproc region, which is a separate Dataproc service that spans all compute regions.

For convenience you can also just add `global` to a for-loop:

```
for REGION in global $(gcloud compute regions list --format="value(name)"); do gcloud dataproc clusters list --region ${REGION}; done
```

Comment: fantastic, thx Dennis. I modified it a little for my own use because I'm writing a tutorial for someone not familiar with GCP and wanted the region to be outputted too, in case anyone is interested: `for region in $(gcloud compute regions list --format="value(name)" | xargs); do    echo "Listing for region: ${region}"; gcloud dataproc clusters list --region ${region};  done`

Answer (score 2):

Having to specify `--region` is how Dataproc command group in gcloud works. Developers Console issues lists requests against all regions (you could [request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_and_create_feature_requests_by_product) for gcloud to do the same).

Alternatively, you can use the `global` mutiregion (which is the gcloud default). This will interact well with your organization policies. If your Organization has region-restricted VM locations you will be able to create VMs in europe but will get an error when doing so elsewhere).

Comment: Thanks @tix, I won't make that request, the command that Dennis supplied works well for me.